# Which preposition follows "persist"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. The program persists the data **in** the database.
> 2. The program persists the data **to** the database.

**In** feels a little more natural to me, but I have no particular basis for that.

Comment: Today I learned that *persist* can be transitive. Interesting. (*In* probably sounds more natural because that's what you'd normally use with the intransitive verb, as in "I persist in my view". You wouldn't say "I persist to my view".)

Comment: what is transitive and why would you normally use *in*  with the transitive verb?

Comment: @vehomzzz: a transitive verb is one which acts on something (technically, it has an object). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb - or ask that as a question on this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program persists the data **in** the
>   database.

Here is what I would say in general:

- save the object in the database
- update the object in the database
- **persist the object in the database** (same as *save* or *update*)
- load the object from the database
- write the object to a file
- read the object from a file

Answer (score 3):

Despite RegDwight's comment that *persist* can be transitive with a direct object, which I didn't know either, I'd suggest that such usage is unusual.

With regard to the actual question, the use of *persist* suggests that the data was in the database before, and that the program doesn't change that; hence *in* should be used here.

So I would write:

> The program causes the data to persist in the database.

**EDIT:** In light of the comments below, note this answer applies to *persist* in its normal, non-programming, contexts. For its use in a programming context, *in* is still correct, but the verb can be used transitively, as in the question.

Comment: Yeah, Merriam-Webster and Co. don't list it as transitive, but Wiktionary actually [does](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persist#Verb), hence my comment.

Comment: @RegDwight: given that the example quoted is quite recent, I wonder if this usage is a new one which hasn't caught on (yet).

Comment: @Steve, @RegDwight: it can be transitive because you can say "persist an object" the same way that you can say "save/load/update/merge an object". It's a technical definition of persist that is particular to programming. Apparently, most dictionaries don't bring that definition of "persist" yet.

Comment: Yeah, that Wiktionary quote and a few Google searches make me think it is limited to programming. In fact, SO seems to be full of questions such as [How to persist event log data in database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/895912/), [How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/287201/), [Best practice to persist config/user info in .NET app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1022127/), [Best practices for using and persisting enums](http://stackoverflow.com/q/746812/), [Persist Local Configuration Data in SharePoint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1947943/)...

Comment: @RegDwight: Just a note on usage, *persist* here does not imply that the data was already there. In fact I'd go as far as saying that usually it is not already present. Persisting is the action of saving the data, I suppose.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would have choosen both. I mean "Into" :-)

Comment: as the database is a container, you place things _into_ it to persist them.